# ConnectionString with external file for SqlConnection

Tags: c#, connection-string, sqlconnection, udl2

C# on VisualStudio 2017. Windows Forms Application.

Hi all. I've read on the web that is not possible to use an **.udl** file in which write a *ConnectionString* for a *SqlConnection*. Is that true at today? And, if yes, there is an alternative way to use an external file for a *ConnectionString* in *SqlConnetion*?

I have to run project in 5 PCs that have different connection strings, for example:

> PC1) Data Source=PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBNEW;User ID=sa;Password=123;
>
> PC2) Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=sa;Password=999;
>
> [...]

Currently I use a string inside the project

```
string connSQL = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBNEW;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123;";
```

that I have to change five times for the five PCs' different connection.

I've tried anyway to connect with an .udl file

```
string connSQL = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFile=C:\\connstring.udl";
```

that contains this

```
[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
Data Source=PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBNEW;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123;
```

but of course it doesn't works.

Any ideas for an alternative solution?

Comment: I would create a login page and pass in the user name and password reading from the connection string in the .Config file using parameters for example 
`<add name="DbConn" connectionString=" Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;User Id={0};Password={1};"/> ` then when you read the config file you want to add 2 extra parameters when you read the .config file..

Comment: @MethodMan Yes, I think it's the best alternative. And studying your answer I managed to find a compromise! Look at my answer below. So thank you very much for the hint. ;)

Comment: not a problem just happy to point you in the right direction and glad you heeded the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. Thanks also to *MethodMan*'s comment I later realized that you can use an external file to compile the *connectionString*, that is **MyProjectName.exe.config**, which is saved in the same directory as the software exe,  and which has the same functions and settings of the **App.config**.

So what I did is create a new *FormConn* where you manually enter data for the *connectionString*, overwrite them in *MyProjectName.exe.config* and link this file to *Form1* for SQL database management. Below the code.

In the *Form1.cs*:

```
using System.Configuration;

public Form1()
{
    //Check if a connectionString already exists
    //To the first slot there is a system configuration so 1 = no custom connectionString
    if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count == 1)
        {
            FormConn frmConn = new FormConn();
            frmConn.ShowDialog();
            try
            {
                //Restart Form1 in the case connectionString has changed
                Application.Restart();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        //Associates the custom connectionString to the string I will use in the code for operations that are connected to the DB.
        StringSQL = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ConnectionString;
}
```

In the *FormConn.cs*:

[image: FormConn (Design)]

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reflections;

string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string appName = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
        string configFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, appName + ".config");
        ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFile;
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var sezione = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");<br>sezione.ConnectionStrings["MyProjectName.Properties.Settings.MyDataSetConnectionString"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + txtDataSource.Text + ";Initial Catalog=" + txtInitialCatalog.Text + ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" + txtUserID.Text + ";Password=" + txtPassword.Text + ";";
        config.Save();
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
        this.Close();
```

And that's what I have inside my *MyProjectName.exe.config*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyProjectName.Properties.Settings.MyDataSetConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=MyPcName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB-1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123psw321"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
</configuration>
```

This worked for me!

Comment: Obviously, you can change the *connectionString* manually and directly from the *MyProjectName.exe.config* file without the need to use the *FormConn*.